# Maximizing $Tr(W^TP\Sigma PW)$ where $P$ is an orthogonal projection matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, covariance

I want to maximize $Tr(W^TP\Sigma PW)$ where $\Sigma$ is a covariance matrix, $P=uu^T$ is an orthogonal projection matrix over a vector $u$, and the maximization is over all $u$ such that $||u||=1$. Does this problem have a closed-form solution?

Thanks!

Comment: $P$ should be $\frac{uu^T}{u^T u}$, otherwise the problem is unbounded.

Comment: thanks, this is constrained optimization, under the constraint $||u||=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\Sigma=VV^T$ (for example via Cholesky decomposition) and $P=\tfrac{uu^T}{u^Tu}$. Setting the [derivative](http://www.matrixcalculus.org/) of

$$Tr(W^TP\Sigma PW)=\langle V^T \tfrac{uu^T}{u^T u} W, V^T \tfrac{uu^T}{u^T u} W\rangle_F = \|V^T \tfrac{uu^T}{u^T u} W\|_F^2$$

equal to zero yields

$$ \frac{VV^T u}{\|V^T u\|_2^2} + \frac{WW^T u}{\|W^T u\|_2^2} \overset{!}{=} 2\frac{u}{\|u\|^2} $$

or equivalently, the fixed-point equation

$$ \frac{1}{2}\bigg(\frac{\|u\|^2_2}{\|V^T u\|_2^2}VV^T u+ \frac{\|u\|_2^2}{\|W^T u\|_2^2} WW^T u\bigg)\overset{!}{=} u $$

Which I would not expect to admit a closed form solution.

One thing one can try is solve the [generalized eigenvalue problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Generalized_eigenvalue_problem), i.e. find $u$ satisfying $A u =\lambda B u$, where $A=-WW^T$, $B=VV^T$. The wikipedia article mentions that in the case when $A$ and $B$ are Hermitian, and $B$ is positive definite, there exists a basis of EV $u_i$ which are $B$-orthogonal. I tried experimenting with it a bit but couldn't get it into any closed form, but maybe you have some more luck.

At the very least, I suspect that the fixed point iteration may offer a simple and efficient way to solve the problem numerically.

Comment: Thanks! would the solution be unique (is the problem convex)? I tried to solve with SGD (is it a worse option compared with fixed-point iteration?) and it seems I do converge to the same solution.

Comment: @user1767774 Yes the problem should be convex. SGD makes no sense to me here, what is the stochastic component? If you mean plain gradient ascent (or gradient ascent on the unconstrained version with alternating projection onto the feasible set) then yes, that would work as well, but it may or may not converge slower than the fixed-point iteration.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was wondering if after finding the optimal $u$, it is possible to continue using fixed-point iteration for finding the *second* best $u$, which is orthogonal to the best $u$ (and the third etc., as is done in PCA)?  I have tried to project $\Sigma$ on the nullspace of the optimal $u$ and repeat the process, but the projected $\Sigma$ becomes rank-deficient and Cholesky decomposition is no longer possible.